# Redshifted blackbody intensity and brightness temperature

Tags: space-expansion, thermal-radiation, redshift

The [spectral radiance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance)<sup>1</sup> (units of $\rm W \ sr^{-1} \ m^{-2} \ Hz^{-1}$) of a  blackbody is given by the Rayleigh-Jeans law in the low frequency limit: $$B_\nu(\nu) = \frac{2 \nu^2 k_B T}{c^2}$$

The redshifted frequency is given by $$\nu(z) = \frac{\nu_0}{1+z}$$

where $\nu_0$ is the un-redshifted frequency. The paper I'm reading claims that $$B_\nu = \frac{B_{\nu,0}}{(1+z)^3}$$ and $$T = \frac{T_0}{1+z}$$

and whilst substitution proves these 2 are consistent with Rayeigh-Jeans law, I fail to see how can one work them out?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I generally try to avoid using the word "intensity" as it can be quite ambiguous. Wikipedia has a good [table of radiometric quantities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometry#Radiometric_quantities) that avoids ambiguity.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As I was writing the question I realised that I could try substituting the expression for $\nu(z)$ into the full Planck law $$B_\nu(T) = \frac{2h\nu^3}{c^2} \frac{1}{e^\frac{h\nu}{k_B T} - 1}$$

of which the Rayleigh-Jeans law is an approximation, yielding

$$B_\nu(z) = \frac{2h\nu_0^3}{c^2 (1+z)^3} \frac{1}{\exp(\frac{h\nu_0}{k_B T(z) (1+z)}) - 1}$$

Considering the exponential, letting $T(z) = T_0 / (1+z)$ is a step in the right direction, removing the factor of $1 / (1+z)$. Then, if

$$B_{\nu,0} = \frac{2h\nu_0^3}{c^2} \frac{1}{\exp(\frac{h\nu_0}{k_B T_0}) - 1}$$

as we expect, clearly $B_\nu(z) = B_{\nu,0} / (1+z)^3$ for this to work.

So I was being a bit dumb, it turns out.